# PUT or PATCH better when submitting an edited Angular form?

Tags: angular, rest, patch, put

I know the difference between PUT and PATCH. But I am struggling to which one should be more appropriate in my use case.

I have got large forms (over 50 form controls in nested form) and small forms (a few form controls) in my app. Both forms allow edit. I need to send the updated form values to backend server.

My hesitation is that, if I do a PUT request, then it would create a huge payload for the large form that even though user may just have edited one or two input fields of those 50 form controls. So this sounds not a good way to always send the whole entity to backend. But, on the contrary, if I do a PATCH request, then I would need to loop through all those 50 form controls and only the ones whose values have been changed will be sent to the backend. In this way, the payload could be minimized, but this sounds clumsy or graceless to me as I'll need to put that "value-changed checking" to all the edit forms.

I searched the past posts and googled, but surprisingly not many talked about it or just used the PUT request due to the form simplicity in their examples.

I hope to hear your advices. Thank you in advance.

p.s. I am using Reactive Form in Angular 7, and I have control on PUT and PATCH rest apis on the backend.

Comment: At what point the PUT request is too large? How many megabytes is this. What is the concern with large PUT requests?

Comment: @Evert I'm not sure. I was just wondering and felt it's a bit weird to send a JSON object containing approximately fifty fields together...

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, you should be using PUT -- because the message is known to be [idempotent](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2), general purpose clients can resend the request if the response appears to have been lost.  With [PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789), you don't get that guarantee.

The exceptions would normally look something like this: the representation of the resource is much larger (in bytes) than the HTTP headers, and the representation of the patch document is much smaller than the representation of the resource.

> If I use PUT, which means I'd send the unmodified fields (username, name and age in this case) to backend as well?

Yes; you send a complete representation of the resource.

> Does it include the unique ID of the entity?

If the representation of the resource includes a unique identifier, then yes that should be part of message-body.

It may help to review the specification of the [PUT method-token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4)

> A successful PUT of a given representation would suggest that a subsequent GET on that same target resource will result in an equivalent representation being sent in a 200 (OK) response.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But let's say I have an edit form for user to edit user info, "username", "name", "contact_no", "age", for example, any of the four fields. I think most of the time in real world, user may just need to update part of the form (i.e. one or two fields, such as contact_no only). If I use PUT, which means I'd send the unmodified fields (username, name and age in this case) to backend as well?

Comment: Also, as the PUT intends to update/ replace the whole entity. Does it include the unique ID of the entity? If I update the user info form, the user_id behind remains the same after the PUT request. Then does this violates its intention? Thanks again.